# Matplotlib X ax range sliding two hours ahead

Tags: python, matplotlib, scale, timedelta

I am looking for a solution to create a graph from the actual time + two hours ahead. So a graph with 20 points over a timespan of two hours. I don't understand how to configure the x ax in a way that it shows only the desired timeframe of two hours. Thanks for any help.

```
#Import modules
from xml.dom import minidom
import urllib.request
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from time import sleep
from random import shuffle
import datetime
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter


# create data 
y = [ 2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,18,16,14,12,10,8,6,4,2]
x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=i) for i in range(len(y))] 



# plot
form=DateFormatter('%H:%M')
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.gcf().axes[0].xaxis.set_major_formatter(form)
plt.show()
```

[Requested Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6P4S.jpg)

Comment: Hi @Jan van Eeden , is there something unclear about the answer I gave you?

Answer (score 0):

You can define the range of the x-axis using `plt.xlim(start, end)`. Here you can do that using:

```
plt.xlim(datetime.datetime.now(), datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=2))
```

If you want a graph with 20 points over a timespan of two hours you also have to change your x-values:

```
x = [datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=2*i/float(len(y))) for i in range(len(y))]
```

Originally the x values went from your starting time to your starting time + i hours (i being the total length of your y), instead of your starting time to your starting time + 2 hours.

This way it spreads all the y values over the coming two hours. This outputs:
[image]

This is not the same as the suggested output because the y-values aren't the same.

Comment: @Jan van Eeden , the problem is partly because your x-values are not correct, I think if you copy the suggested line you'll get exactly what you expected.

Comment: Wow Nathan, Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I ment!!! Great!! Next time you have a problem, I will do my best to help you :) Have a nice day!!

Comment: @JanvanEeden glad to hear it's working :) Now you can accept the answer so other people know it's finished.